# Create taxonomy reference field programatically in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms

How to create taxonomy reference field programatically in a custom form?

```
$tags = array();// get taxonomy terms from a vocabulary.

$form['custom_tags'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $tags,
  '#title' => $this->t('Preffered Tags'),
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('custom_tags') ? $this->store->get('custom_tags') : '',
);
```

How can I get taxonomy terms from a vocabulary? Or how to create a term reference field in custom form?

Answer (score 2):

I did it by following method. If any other better way to achieve this, please suggest.

```
$tag_terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('tags');
$tags = array();
foreach ($tag_terms as $tag_term) {
    $tags[$tag_term->tid] = $tag_term->name;
}

$form['custom_tags'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $tags,
  '#title' => $this->t('Preffered Tags'),
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('custom_tags') ? $this->store->get('custom_tags') : '',
);
```